# Oracle 11G REGEXP_SUBSTR function

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have a data like.

> "sometext"  HostAddress: 10.10.10.100 / 198.168.34.63 "sometext"
>   "newline" "sometext"  HostAddress: 10.10.10.100 "sometext" "newline"

using REGEXPR_SUBSTRING I am able to achieve HostAddress: 10.10.10.100 ie. first object adjacent to HostAddress: string.but not second string i.e 1998.168.34.63 I want to output like HostAddress: IP / IP using Regexp_substr function.

I am using below function to obtain specified filed from row data.

```
   SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('HostAddress: 10.10.10.100 / 198.168.34.63 sometext','HostAddress: ([[:alnum:]]+\.?){3,4} ') FROM Dual;
```

Thank you in advance ......

Comment: Please clarify:  What you show as "input", is that a single string from which you want to retrieve the IP address? It shows HostAddress: twice, do you want to extract only the first pair, but not the IP address after the second HostAddress: substring? Also, does your input string have newlines (rather than the substring "newline"), and should that mean anything in the output?

Comment: @ mathguy I think you can see the exact output by executing my sql queries in dummy   table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find the code below

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('HostAddress: 10.10.10.100 / 198.168.34.63 sometext','HostAddress: ([[:alnum:]]+.+ /?){1,2}') FROM Dual;
```

the result is : HostAddress: 10.10.10.100 / 198.168.34.63 
Hope this will solve your problem

Comment: Hi Ajeesh, Thank you for reply, I checked the given query run perfectly fine but returning the two extra words after second field, Suppose input string like _"This is nobita and pikachu HostAddress: 10.10.10.10 / 192.168.2.154 gdhsg hjdsg hdhsk"_ then above Query return result **HostAddress: 10.10.10.10 / 192.168.2.154 gdhsg hjdsg**. I want result only **HostAddress: 10.10.10.10 / 192.168.2.154** also noted IP value is dynamic.

Comment: Please use this query "SELECT
  REGEXP_SUBSTR('This is nobita and pikachu HostAddress: 10.10.10.10 / 192.168.2.154 gdhsg hjdsg hdhsk',
                'HostAddress: ([[:alnum:]]+\.?){1,4}/? / ([[:alnum:]]+\.?){1,4}/?') "IP Address"   FROM DUAL; ". It retrieves only "HostAddress: 10.10.10.10 / 192.168.2.154". Hope it solves your problem. Please let me know, if you got any easy alternate solution.

Comment: Perfect Ajeesh... Got a expected output .. Thank you very much... :)